# Jquery based menu to hide show divs

Tags: jquery

I have a menu. It is a set of anchor links that make up Menu items.  When menu items are clicked they show particular div and hide the rest.  Will be adding more menu items, so there is a need to make the code reusable and extendable.  The code works, but it isn't pretty, and I would like to cut down on the repetition of code.  Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

```
 <div id="product-table-links" class="product-table-links"><a href="#" id="food-product-all" class="table-anchor">All</a>
<a href="#" id="food-product-button1" class="table-anchor" data-page="food1">Food Type 1</a>
<a href="#" id="food-product-button2" class="table-anchor" data-page="food2">Food Type 2</a>
<a href="#" id="food-product-button3" class="table-anchor" data-page="food3">Food Type 3</a>
<a href="#" id="food-product-button4" class="table-anchor" data-page="food4">Food Type 4</a>
<a href="#" id="food-product-button5" class="table-anchor" data-page="food5">Food Type 5</a>
<a href="#" id="food-product-button6" class="table-anchor" data-page="food6">Food Type 6</a>
<a href="#" id="food-product-button7" class="table-anchor" data-page="food7">Food Type 7</a>
<a href="#" id="food-product-button8" class="table-anchor" data-page="food8">Food Type 8</a></div>
<div class="product-divTable" style="width: 100%;" >
<div class="product-divTableBody">
<div class="product-divTableRow" id="food1">
  <div class="product-divTableCell">food section 1</div>
</div>
<div class="product-divTableRow" id="food2">
  <div class="product-divTableCell">food section 2</div>
</div>
<div class="product-divTableRow" id="food3">
  <div class="product-divTableCell">food section 3</div>
</div>
<div class="product-divTableRow" id="food4">
  <div class="product-divTableCell">food section 4</div>
</div>
<div class="product-divTableRow" id="food5">
  <div class="product-divTableCell">food section 5</div>
</div>
<div class="product-divTableRow" id="food6">
  <div class="product-divTableCell">food section 6</div>
</div>
<div class="product-divTableRow" id="food7">
  <div class="product-divTableCell">food section 7</div>
</div>
<div class="product-divTableRow" id="food8">
  <div class="product-divTableCell">food section 8</div>
</div>
</div>
```

```
    $(document).ready(function(){       

          $("#food-product-button1").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
              $('a.table-anchor').removeClass("active");
              $(this).addClass("active");
            $('.product-divTableRow').hide();
              $("#food1").show();
          });

            $("#food-product-button2").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('a.table-anchor').removeClass("active");
              $(this).addClass("active");
            $('.product-divTableRow').hide();
              $("#food2").show();
          });

           $("#food-product-button3").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
               $('a.table-anchor').removeClass("active");
              $(this).addClass("active");
             $('.product-divTableRow').hide();
              $("#food3").show();
          });

            $("#food-product-button4").click(function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
                $('a.table-anchor').removeClass("active");
              $(this).addClass("active");
             $('.product-divTableRow').hide();
             $("#food4").show();
          });

          $("#food-product-button5").click(function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
              $('a.table-anchor').removeClass("active");
              $(this).addClass("active");
               $('.product-divTableRow').hide();
              $("#food5").show();
          });

            $("#food-product-button6").click(function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
                $('a.table-anchor').removeClass("active");
              $(this).addClass("active");
                $('.product-divTableRow').hide();
              $("#food6").show();
          });

            $("#food-product-button7").click(function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
                $('a.table-anchor').removeClass("active");
              $(this).addClass("active");
                 $('.product-divTableRow').hide();
              $("#food7").show();
          });

            $("#food-product-button8").click(function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
                $('a.table-anchor').removeClass("active");
              $(this).addClass("active");
                $('.product-divTableRow').hide();
              $("#food8").show();
          });

            $("#food-product-all").click(function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
                $('a.table-anchor').removeClass("active");
              $(this).addClass("active");
              $('.product-divTableRow').show();
          });

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
 $('.table-anchor').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('a.table-anchor').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass("active");
    var foodToShow = $(this).attr('data-page');
    $('.product-divTableRow').hide();
    $('#' + foodToShow).show();
});
$('#food-product-all').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('a.table-anchor').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.product-divTableRow').show();
});
```

Just make sure to keep data-page on anchor and id for div the same